# how to use scim in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, ime, multilingual

I installed scim IME in my ubuntu 10.04 linux.  I also installed hindi and gujrati support/fonts  from System->Administration->Language support.

I logged in and logged out.

However, I have no clue how to use scim. I type scim, and some icon shows in the tray. I don't understand much of options in the menu.  And I tried a document in openoffice  or a file in gvim, but cant find any way to type in hindi.  In openoffice, I tried some hindi fonts but they all type in english.

please tell me how to use scim!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most IMEs require you to press a specific keystroke to activate them; check the SCIM configuration to confirm what it is. Also, you may need to use another tool in order to enable the IM for the entire session, but I don't know what it's called in Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks.. I was missing the keystroke (Ctl + space) in case of scim.. I thought starting scim is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the following package:

```
sudo aptitude install libkmfl0 libkmflcomp0 kmflcomp scim-kmfl-imengine
```

Run

```
 scim-setup
```

Expand the "IMEngine" and click KMFL

Click on "Install" and browse to the folder where the compiles keyboard layout files reside

Open text editor press `Ctlr + space`  to select your installed language

Comment: thanks... could not find KMFL... but, the activating keystroke/shortcut + rebooting after installation worked...

Comment: yes.. actually what I was missing was that I need to press some keystroke to activate it.. solved it before reading your answer, hence accepted his... thanks for yours too though as it would solved it as well